# Unit testing: Sending complex object as a input parameter to my test method using MSTest

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I'm trying to send a `List<DataStatusItem>` as a input parameter to my unit test method using `DataRow` attribute as below,

```
[TestClass]
public class UpdateProcessingTestController
{
    private List<DataStatusItem> DataStatusItemsTestSetup = new List<DataStatusItem>() {
            new DataStatusItem { DataItemID = 1, DataItemCurrentStatusID = 1, DataItemStatusID = 1, DateEffective = DateTime.Now }
    };

    private readonly Mock<IEmployee> moqEmployee;

    public UpdateProcessingTestController()
    {
        moqEmployee = new Mock<IEmployee>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [DataRow(DataStatusItemsTestSetup, 1, 8, 1)] // **This is where it is throwing me compilation error**
    public void SetDataItems(List<DataStatusItem> DataStatusItems,int brand, int dataType, int processingStatus)
}
```

Please let me know how to send the List as a input parameter to my test method.

Comment: You cannot pass object that is not known at compile time. You can only pass const values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please tell me, how to pass the object with MSTest unit testing. Or should i just declare them within the test method definition?

Comment: Use [DynamicData attribute](https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx-docs/blob/master/RFCs/006-DynamicData-Attribute.md) for that.

Comment: Not really a direct answer, but consider using nunit or xunit. Nunit certainly supports this out of the box with `TestCaseSource` and `TestCaseData`. If you don't want to move the whole project over, even though it's pretty easy to do so, you can use multiple test frameworks in the same project, just remember to add the appropriate test adapter package.

Comment: @GeorgeHelyar No need to switch the test framework for that any more. MSTest V2 aka testfx can do it since June 2017.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [DynamicData Attribute](https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx-docs/blob/master/RFCs/006-DynamicData-Attribute.md), Here is an example:

```
public class DataStatusItem
{
    public int DataItemID { get; set; }
    public int DataItemCurrentStatusID { get; set; }
    public int DataItemStatusID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateEffective { get; set; }
}

[TestClass]
public class UpdateProcessingTestController
{
    static IEnumerable<object[]> DataStatusItemsTestSetup
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new object[]
                {
                    new List<DataStatusItem>
                    {
                        new DataStatusItem { DataItemID = 1, DataItemCurrentStatusID = 1, DataItemStatusID = 1, DateEffective = DateTime.Now },
                        new DataStatusItem { DataItemID = 2, DataItemCurrentStatusID = 2, DataItemStatusID = 2, DateEffective = DateTime.Now },
                    },
                    1, // brand
                    2, // dataType
                    3  // processingStatus
                }
            };
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [DynamicData(nameof(DataStatusItemsTestSetup))]
    public void SetDataItems(List<DataStatusItem> dataStatusItems, int brand, int dataType, int processingStatus)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(2, dataStatusItems.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, brand);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, dataType);
        Assert.AreEqual(3, processingStatus);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use concrete types instead of the `object`?

Comment: Sure. Just replace `IEnumerable<object[]>` with `IEnumerable<MyClass[]>`, `return new[]` with `return new List<MyClass[]>`, and `new object[]` with `new MyClass[]`. All good.

Comment: Will it restrict the parameters of my test method to a single type?